# predicate priority in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query in where I need to return only one row from a table based on a descending order of predicate preference. For Example:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Tbl
WHERE   col = 1
OR      col = 2 
OR      col = 3;
```

In the above scenario, if col = 1, I don't want to return data where col = 2 or 3, only data where col = 1.

If col != 1 but col = 2 or 3, i only want to return data for col = 2 and so on.

Is there an easy way to achieve this? Apologies in advance if the way I have explained this is confusing.

**EDIT**

To clear up the confusion, please see the following sample data:

```
With tbl As (
Select  1 As RECORD_ID, 'This is the string I want to return' str,                            'FIRST'  priority   From dual Union All
Select  1,              'This is the string i want to return, if CONDITION1 does not exist',  'SECOND'            From dual Union All
Select  1,              'this is the string i will return if i find no others',               'DEFAULT'           From dual Union All
Select  2,              'This is the string i want to return, if CONDITION1 does not exist',  'SECOND'            From dual Union All
Select  2,              'this is the string i will return if i find no others',               'DEFAULT'           From dual
)
Select  RECORD_ID,
        str
From    tbl
Where   xxx;
```

So in the above example, if I queried for RECORD_ID 1 I would want FIRST string returned, and if I queried for RECORD_ID 2, I should get SECOND.

At the moment, all three strings will return.

Comment: Is `col` mandatory? Having to handle nulls complicates things.

Comment: edit: @Prateek, right I misunderstood it...

Comment: @Ben373 he means to return result based on condition matching. Rownum would return first row right?

Comment: Surely `col` cannot be equal to 1 if it is equal to 2. You may want to add some sample data and expected results.

Comment: @mustaccio it is across multiple rows of data. The object is to have a different string returned based on what configuration is available, with a preference for which row is returned. e.g. if I have a row where col = 1, I should return this and disregard results where col = 2 or col = 3, even if those records exist. I effectively want to match on my first condition, but if there are no matches, to match on my second, and so on. I hope this helps clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses ordering:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      where col in (1, 2, 3)
      order by (case col when 1 then 1 when 2 then 2 when 3 then 3 end)
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

Obviously, in your case, the `order by` could be `order by col`, but the general situation is to use `case`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, do you not need `end` in your case expression like this, `(case col when 1 then 1 when 2 then 2 when 3 then 3 end)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT  t1.*
FROM    Tbl t1
WHERE   t1.col in (1,2,3)
ORDER BY t1.col
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: "first" by what ordering? There is none in your query.

Answer (score 0):

A standard and common way of doing this is with `ROW_NUMBER()`. Oracle `ROWNUM` is not portable:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LENGTH(priority)) AS rn
    FROM Tbl t WHERE col in (1, 2, 3)
)
SELECT * FROM data WHERE rn = 1;
```

Here's are other variations, essentially identical, that use `min()` instead. **EDIT:** With updated requirements these would tweaks to get the correct ordering but in principle they could still work.

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl
WHERE col = (SELECT MIN(col) FROM Tbl);
```

More like the first one:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT t.*, MIN(col) OVER () AS mn
    FROM Tbl t WHERE col in (1, 2, 3)
)
SELECT * FROM data WHERE col = mn;
```

You might want to look at the query plans to determine which one is the best for you although I suspect your table only has a few rows.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that using integers was for example only. I have updated my question. Is it possible to give the different predicates this order?

Comment: @mmartin2409 Yes, you can just use another ordering expression.

Comment: Coincidentally `length()` will give you the proper ordering. The long way is just an explicit `case` expression: `case priority when 'first' then 1 when 'second' then 2 else 3 end`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the selectivity of each predicate, you may get benefits by separating the query out into individual components, ie,

```
SQL> select * from
  2  ( select x
  3    from   t1
  4    where  x = :b1   -- first condition
  5    union all
  6    select x
  7    from   t1
  8    where  y = :b1   -- second condition
  9  )
 10  where rownum = 1
 11  /
```

If the first query in the UNION ALL finds a row, then we can avoid the second query altogether.

You can find a worked example proving the "short circuit" processing here

https://connor-mcdonald.com/2016/03/14/the-first-matching-row/